# Linux Active Directory login failed because of password

Tags: linux, samba, active-directory, authentication, kerberos

I have a Linux machine that has a connection to the AD. kinit command works correct (it has no output when I run it). But when I try to login to this Linux, I get "Access denied" error.

```
Dec 20 16:33:10 <hostname> sshd[3667]: Failed password for myuser@MYDOMAIN from 2.2.2.2 port 59222 ssh2
```

The password that I typed is not false, I'm sure.

Domain names in the krb5.conf file are upper case.

nsswitch.conf file is like below:

```
passwd:     winbind files sss
shadow:     files sss
group:      winbind files sss
```

testjoin:

```
# net ads testjoin
Join is OK
```

kinit:

```
# kinit myuser@MYDOMAIN.COM
Password for myuser@MYDOMAIN:
#
```

There is no problem as I understand about kinit or my password.

How can I fix that fake password issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mapping does not work correctly. We should remove trivia db and mapping files with below commands:

```
#service winbind stop
#service smb stop
#net cache flush
#rm -f /var/lib/samba/*.tdb
#rm -f /var/lib/samba/group_mapping.ldb
#systemctl start winbind
#systemctl start smb
```

After that winbind will can check id from Active Directory.